# Regions are gone

Tags: 7, theming

I work with the [Omega](http://drupal.org/project/omega) theme, but whenever I try to edit my regions, they are completely empty...

As you can see on the image, there are no regions available, although there is content placed inside them and on the frontend, it all looks fine.

I've flushed the cash and ran cron multiple times, but with no luck...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with a sub-theme, the regions of the parent theme are not inherited. Check out [Creating a Sub-theme](http://drupal.org/node/225125) if this is the case.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but the regions of my parent theme are empty as well... That's really odd!

Answer (score 0):

The question is old, but maybe somebody humbles over it here from google, like me:

This can have many reasons. Without any knowledge about your setup I would assume it is a jquery issue not showing your regions. Many contrib modules want to use newer jquery versions, while Drupal core stucks on older versions. Often it is even best to have two different versions running. One for frontpage, and one for admin area. Did you try already to install jquery_update module and play around with loaded jquery versions? In most cases that has fixed my admin area issues if some forms etc. were not showing correctly ... just my two (late) cents ...